# Not getting tags html in page source

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, single-page-application, multilingual

I have multilingual single page html application where I set html of tags by calling function on `document.ready`. However I am not getting html of any tag in page source when I view page on `View Page Source`. How can I get the tags in page source? `document.ready` is in the last script tag of the page.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var lang = // get the language.
    translateFunction(lang);
});
```

Below function is in `js` file. This file is added above the last script tag (i.e. `document.ready` script).

```
function translateFunction(lang) {
    $("[tkey]").each(function (index)
    {
        var strTr = lang_resource[lang][$(this).attr('tkey')];
        $(this).html(strTr);
    });
}

<h1 tkey="firstH1"></h1>
```

Language wise data is in `json` format in the same js file with translate function.

When I view the page source, I see only

```
<h1 tkey="firstH1"></h1>
```

Where it needs to be like below,

```
<h1 tkey="firstH1">Anything from the translate function.</h1>
```

On the page, you can see the desired output, but in the page source, I am not getting html set. What I want to do is, I want set html of the tags in javascript on document.ready. How to do it?

**EDIT**
We want to add meta tags. And set keywords and description language wise. This is the main concern. The keywords and description are set in `translate` function. Will the crawler take the keywords and description?

We have two links language wise in site map. So when user select say french language, it will redirect to `www.mysite.com?lang=fr` and all the tags are set in french language. So the meta keywords and description.

Comment: I know how to get it. I want to set it. And also that must be fetched in page source ( when you view page source).

Comment: Page source doesn't show the html as it is after it's been updated.  Use the browser's debug window - Chrome:Elements, IE:DOM Explorer.  Easiest way is, in chrome, right click your element and select `Inspect`

Comment: @freedomn-m : We have to add meta tags in this page. Now meta tags are also in different languages. So google crawler would not see any keyword or meta description.

Comment: Google crawler doesn't load your page, run javascript and then *look at page source of the browser* - it doesn't use a browser.  That's not how google crawler works.  Why didn't you mention it was for google crawler in the question?    The browser feature "view page **source**" looks at ...... the page *source*, not the *current page html*.   Google crawler doesn't use a *browser* so doesn't have a "browser feature view page source" - it does it differently.

Comment: ie - it's working fine, but you're looking in the wrong place to see the effect

Comment: @freedomn-m : I have edited my question and mentioned that it's about crawler.

Answer (score -2):

Firstly if this is the exact code,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var lang = // get the language.
    translateFunction(lang);
});
```

there is error in itself...

there should be some value for  `var lang`

Comment: If you can see there is comment, `// get the language.` That means there is code to get the language.

Comment: This is *clearly* not the code that's being run - otherwise OP would be complaining that his code doesn't run.  It's provided so that we can see that the `translateFunction` is being run from document ready after the DOM has loaded.   (otherwise everyone would just jump in and say "run your code in doc ready")